# how can a void function be called to the main, if there are no returns?

Tags: c++

I wanted to create a function that retrieves all the information from previous functions within the same Class, and prints the values that were returned in the format of a bunch of `cout` statements, there is nothing for me to return in this PrintStatement() function, so I would create a void function, correct? My issue is in the `int main()`, I cannot `cout` a void function.

this is my account header file, and the function piece from my account.cpp file.

```
class Account {

public:
    //Object constructor
     Account(char firstName[], char lastName[], char sinNumber[], double balance, int accountType, int transactions);

    //Object operations
    double DepositAmt(double amount);
    double WithdrawAmt(double amount);
    void   PrintStatement();
    double getFinalBalance(double fbal);
    string getAccountType();
    double getTransactions (double Deposit, double Withdraw);

private:
    //Object properties
    char firstName[255];
    char lastName[255];
    char sinNumber[255];
    double balance;
    int accountType;
    int transactions;
};


void Account::PrintStatement()
{

        cout << "First Name:    " << firstName    << endl;
        cout << "Last Name:     " << lastName     << endl;
        cout << "SIN Number:    " << sinNumber    << endl;
        cout << "Account Type:  " << accountType  << endl;
        cout << "Final Balance: " << balance      << endl;
        cout << "Transactions:  " << transactions << endl;


};
```

the global variables have already been initialized.

What I've tried:

I originally tried to `cout << account.PrintStatement() << endl;` however I get an `error C2679 (binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

I thought maybe changing things to apply to a string function instead would work, but instead I get a bunch of int conversion errors etc.

I'm unsure of what to do.

I am ***required*** to put these in a function just to be clear.

I tried using this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766858/how-to-call-void-function-from-main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766858/how-to-call-void-function-from-main%20Question) to help me, it made sense that the poster was using a reference, but I do not have that. Is there another way?

Comment: What's issue in simply calling `account.PrintStatement() ;` ?

Comment: When you `cout` something i a function called from main it will still print it to the `cout` output stream used in main :)

Comment: @P0W there was no issue, i thought I had tried that but I must have made a mistake somewhere when doing it. Just my own stupidity lol. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I originally tried to `cout << account.PrintStatement() << endl;`

Well, the expression `account.PrintStatement()` is abject nothingness because the function has a `void` return type. As you've indicated, the function returns nothing, so there is nothing to stream to `cout`.

The function *itself* has already streamed a bunch of stuff to `cout`, fulfilling all your `cout`y needs. So, simply invoke it:

```
account.PrintStatement();
```

That's it!

Comment: lol I want to slap myself so hard....i thought i tried that but clearly I didn't lol. I can honestly say I have learned so much from this one assignment giving me headache after headache lol. And you all have been awesome. Thank you! i can finally submit this and get some sleep lol.

Answer (score 4):

Just call the method on your instance of the class. It doesn't need to return anything; it will do the counts you want and then return to main.

Answer (score 2):

When we use `cout<<something_here`, the compiler will interpret it as "print the value of `something_here`". Now, `something_here` can be a lot of things. When it is a function, `cout` will print the value returned by the function. In your case, the return type is `void` i.e. nothing. So, there is nothing to print.

To fix your issue, you can directly call `account.PrintStatement();` since you have already printed what you wanted to print inside this function.